# Плавное затухание адресной светодиодной ленты (C++)

Tags: c++, arduino

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать код эффекта для светодиодной ленты WS2812b.
Хочу сделать так, чтобы плавно загорался рандомно выбранный цвет, затем плавно затухал, и дальше тоже самое, но с другим рандомно выбранным цветом
Пробовала делать так, но ничего не получается:

```
void party()
{
    if (millis() - timing > 10000)
    {
        timing = millis();
        if (r_flag == true)
        {
            a = random(0, 255);
            b = random(0, 255);
            c = random(0, 255);
            r_flag = false;
        };
        if ((d < a) && (e < b) && (f < c))
        {
            if (d < a + 1)
            {
                d = d + 1;
            };
            if (e < b + 1)
            {
                e = e + 1;
            };
            if (f < c + 1)
            {
                f = f + 1;
            };
            if (n < NUM_LEDS)
            {
                n = n + 1;
                strip.setPixelColor(n, strip.Color(d, e, f));
                strip.show();
            }
            n = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (d > 1)
            {
                d = d - 1;
            };
            if (e > 1)
            {
                e = e - 1;
            };
            if (f > 1)
            {
                f = f - 1;
            };
            if (n < NUM_LEDS)
            {
                n = n + 1;
                strip.setPixelColor(n, strip.Color(d, e, f));
                strip.show();
            }
            n = -1;
        }

        while (n < NUM_LEDS)
        {
            n = n + 1;
            strip.setPixelColor(n, strip.Color(d, e, f));
            strip.show();
        }
        n = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут подойдет использование [цветовой модели HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

По этой модели цвет состоит из 3-х компонент:

- H - определяет оттенок(задается углом)
- S - задает его насыщенность(чем меньше тем бледнее и ближе к белому)
- V - определяет яркость(Больше - ярче, ноль соответствует черному)

То есть , чтобы задать цвет нужно будет генерировать значения для `H` и `S`, а изменение яркости - через изменение `V`.
Это сильно упростит задачку.

В библиотеке `Adafruit NeoPixel` для задания цвета в формате `HSV` существует [метод](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel/blob/master/Adafruit_NeoPixel.cpp#L2374) `Adafruit_NeoPixel::ColorHSV`.

А для заполнения ленты подойдет [метод](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel/blob/master/Adafruit_NeoPixel.cpp#L2341) `Adafruit_NeoPixel::fill`.

Если не задумываться о многозадачности, то в псевдокоде это выглядело бы как то так

```pascal
while true:
    // выбор цвета
    H := select(0, 65535)
    S := select(0, 255)
    
    // нарастающая яркость
    for V := 0 to 255:
        color = Adafruit_NeoPixel::ColorHSV(H, S, V)
        strip.fill(color)
        strip.show()
        wait(delay)

    // убывающая яркость
    for V := 255 downto 0:
        color = Adafruit_NeoPixel::ColorHSV(H, S, V)
        strip.fill(color)
        strip.show()
        wait(delay)
```

Для поддержки многозадачности нужно избавится от циклов, преобразовав алгоритм в [машину состояний](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Это решается через выделение переменных, шагов и переходов между шагами

Выделим перечисление, которое будет определять текущий шаг:

```cpp
enum class Step
{
    SELECT, // выбрать цвет
    RUN_UP, // нарастить яркость
    WAIT_UP,
    RUN_DOWN, // снизить яркость
    WAIT_DOWN,
};
```

Объявим структуру с состоянием алгоритма

```cpp
struct State
{
    Step step = Step::SELECT; // текущий шаг, начинаем с выбора цвета
    
    // текущий цвет
    uint16_t H;
    uint8_t  S;
    uint8_t  V;
    
    unsigned long time; // для замены delay
};

State state{};
```

добавим несколько вспомогательных функций

```cpp
// Утилита для заполнения ленты
void fill_strip(const State& state)
{
    auto color = Adafruit_NeoPixel::ColorHSV(state.H, state.S, state.V);
    strip.fill(color);
    strip.show();
}

// проверка, что ожидание завершено
bool wait_is_done(const State& state)
{
    constexpr auto period = 10UL;
    
    return millis() >= state.time + period;   
}
```

Опишем шаги и переходы

```cpp
// выбор цвета
void do_select_color(State &state)
{
        state.H = random(0, 0xFFFF);
        state.S = random(0, 255);
        state.V = 0;
        
        state.step = Step::RUN_UP; // цвет выбран, идем дальше
}

// увеличение яркости
void do_run_up(State &state)
{
    fill_strip(state);
    
    state.V += 1;
    state.time = millis();
    state.step = Step::WAIT_UP; // подождать
}

// подождать
void do_wait_up(State &state)
{
    if (wait_is_done(state)) // ожидание окончено
    {
        auto do_run = state.V != 255; // Максимальная яркость еще не достигнута?
        
        state.step = do_run ? Step::RUN_UP : Step::RUN_DOWN;
    }
}


// уменьшение яркости
void do_run_down(State &state)
{
    fill_strip(state);
    
    state.V -= 1;
    state.time = millis();
    state.step = Step::WAIT_DOWN; // подождать
}

// подождать
void do_wait_down(State &state)
{
    if (wait_is_done(state)) // ожидание окончено
    {
        auto do_run = state.V != 0; // Минимальная яркость еще не достигнута?
        
        state.step = do_run ? Step::RUN_DOWN : Step::RUN_SELECT;
    }
}
```

Ну и соберем их через `switch`

```cpp
// шаг цикла
void run_show(State& state)
{

    switch(state.step)
    {
    case Step::SELECT:
        do_select_color(state);
        break;
    case Step::RUN_UP:
        do_run_up(state);
        break;
    case Step::WAIT_UP:
        do_wait_up(state);
        break;
    case Step::RUN_DOWN:
        do_run_down(state);
        break;
    case Step::WAIT_DOWN:
        do_wait_down(state);
        break;
    }
}
```